# A different way of logging in using 2 tables in a single database

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I made a login for a website.

I made a successful one using 1 account table in a database.

Now I made another table for another account. Both tables are different in attributes that is why I separated them.

I am having a hard time log-in the second one in by using this algorithim.

The inputted login and password come from another page using a HTML Form.

```
<?php
    //Start session
    session_start();

    //Include database connection details
    require_once("config.php");
    require("clean.php");

    //Array to store validation errors
    $errmsg_arr = array();

    //Validation error flag
    $errflag = false;

    //Sanitize the POST values
    $login = clean($_POST['login']);
    $password = clean($_POST['password']);

    //Input Validations
    if($login == '') {
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'Login ID missing';
        $errflag = true;
    }
    if($password == '') {
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'Password missing';
        $errflag = true;
    }

    //If there are input validations, redirect back to the login form
    if($errflag) {
        $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
        session_write_close();
        header("location: login-form.php");
        exit();
    }

    //Create query for patient
    $qry="SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE login='$login' AND password='".md5($password)."'";
    $result=mysql_query($qry);

//Check whether the query was successful or not
    if($result) {
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
            //Login Successful User
            session_regenerate_id();
            $user_info = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']  = $user_info['ID_NO'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $user_info['FNAME'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_admin']      = $user_info['admin'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_itResult']      = $user_info['itResult'];
            //print "Login a success!";
            session_write_close();
            header("location: member-index.php");
            exit();
        }
        else {
                //Create query for 
                $qry="SELECT * FROM specialist_info WHERE spec_username='$login' AND spec_password='".md5($password)."'";
                $result2=mysql_query($qry);

                //Check whether the query was successful or not
                if($result2) {

                    if(mysql_num_rows($result2) == 1) {
                        //Login Successful User

                        session_regenerate_id();
                        $specialist_info = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
                        $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']  = $specialist_info['spec_id'];
                        $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $specialist_info['name'];
                        $_SESSION['SESS_admin'] = 1;

                        //print "Login a success!";
                        session_write_close();
                        header("location: member-index.php");
                        exit();
                        }

                    else {
                        //Login failed
                        header("location: login-failed.php");
                        exit();
                        }
                    }
            }
    }
        else {
        die("Query failed");
    }
}
?>
```

I was able to log-in the first(meaning there is connection between PHP and MySQL) account however I could not in the second.

From what i follow, I could not get in this one. "if(mysql_num_rows($result2) == 1)"
I know there is data in the second table in the database because i checked it(there is MD5 yes).

Maybe my logic is wrong. Suggestions? :D Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the code (will review later) but you could try refactoring your tables so you have a separate table that contains user attributes, this allows you to be dynamic with your attributes so you don't have to create a different table every time you have a different type of user.

EDIT:
Try:
`var_dump(mysql_num_rows($result2))` if this shows the return value is false something is wrong with the query, otherwise it doesn't match any rows.

Comment: If an answer is helpful, or even better, solves your problem please consider accepting or voting up. What did the var_dump show?

Comment: No, the result shows the function returns an integer with value 0. This means that there are zero matching rows in your table. If the result of var_dump had been bool(false) it would mean something is wrong with the query. You should now try to find out why your syntactically correct query doesn't match any rows. Try printing the query and matching this to your DB.

Answer (score 0):

> Now I made another table for another account. Both tables are different in attributes that is why I separated them.

No.

They're both for the same purpose - You should be using a single table, and if you can't accomodate the differences between the 2 types of entities within a single table efficiently add 1 or 2 tables with a 1:1 non-oblig relationship.

But leaving that for now, even with this messy and potentially dangerous structure, you don't need 2 queries and all that code:

```
SELECT 'std' AS src, id_no, fname, admin, itResult
FROM user_info 
WHERE login='$login' 
AND password='".md5($password)."'
UNION
SELECT 'ext' AS src, spec_id AS id_no, name AS fname, 1 AS admin, NULL AS iResult
FROM specialist_info 
WHERE spec_username='$login' 
AND spec_password='".md5($password)
```

Obviously this breaks if you've got the same username/password in both - but really

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
```

is redundant anyway - you only need to check

```
if ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
```

A lot of the code you've posted is irrelevant to the problem you've described - but the total absence of comments / logging / debugging provides us with little means of working out whats going on. The 2 combined strongly suggest that you've not bothered to clean out the irrelevant bits before poasting it here. Had you maybe included some debugging / logging functionality you might have been able to work it out yourself.